# SQL not returning the MAX version needed from the dataset

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataset for example:

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1.2.1 |
| First | 1.2.2 |
| Second | 1.2.0 |
| Second | 1.2.2 |
| Third | 1.3.1 |
| Third | 1.3.2 |
| Fifth | 1.0.1 |
| Fifth | 1.2.2 |
| Fourth | 2.2.2 |
| Fourth | 1.2.2 |

I need to return the unique name with the highest version. I initially used `MAX(Version)` and this gave me back the incorrect version as it seems it's a string.

So I've used `MAX(CAST('Version') AS DECIMAL)` as Version` also tried with FLOAT and this brought me back null values as the Version.

Is there anything I can use to bring me back the highest Version only so the dataset would be like:

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1.2.2 |
| Second | 1.2.2 |
| Third | 1.3.2 |
| Fifth | 1.2.2 |
| Fourth | 2.2.2 |

Edit:

I will show a different more accurate example with SQL as it's not bringing me the highest version with using just MAX alone.

```
SELECT Name, Version from table where Name IN ("First")
GROUP BY Name
```

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1.3.0 |
| First | 1.8.0 |
| First | 1.11.0 |
| First | 1.9.2 |
| Fifth | 1.12.0 |
| Fifth | 1.7.2 |

From this if I do:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Version) from table where Name IN ("First")
GROUP BY Name
```

This returns:

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1.9.2 |

Comment: Unfortunately, the sample data you've chosen to present doesn't include any of the problematic cases - such as `2.10` sorting lower than `2.2`.

Comment: updated the above, its not returning me the right version unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Spark SQL you can use `transform` to get an array of integers like `[1, 12, 0]` for `1.12.0`, then you can get the maximum array for each name, and join them with `.` to get back the original version number.

```sql
select 
    Name, 
    concat_ws('.', max(transform(split(Version, '\\.'), x -> int(x)))) as Version 
from mytable 
group by Name
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to have done it, but only issue is that the data shows as an array, is there anyway to have the final output as the same format i.e 1.12.0?

Comment: the `concat_ws` should give back the original format. Did you put that in your query?

Comment: yep I missed that, thank you so much. Just saved me from a tool I published live with that bug :)

Comment: Only problem here is this doesn't solve the issue of having Version say 1.9.8 against 19.1, it would bring back 1.9.8 and should bring back 19.1 as it's the higher version. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: after splitting into an array, [19, 1] should rank higher than [1, 9, 8]. isn't that the case?

Comment: I haven't found a case for it, but wouldn't this code compare 198 to 191?

Comment: No, it only splits on `.`, so it will remain as 19 (an integer).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `HierarchyId` in for your query .

```
 select Name,Max(Version) as Version from table order by
 CAST('/'+Version+'/' as hierarchyID)
```

This solution should work on SQL server2008